# A (simple?) question about continuous functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization, continuity

[EDIT to restrict the function domain to a compact interval, and adapt some of my thoughts.]

Suppose I have a continuous and twice differentiable function $f_a(x)$ that maps some compact interval $[\underline{x}, \overline{x}]$ to the reals, where $a\geq 0$ is a parameter and $f$ is also continuous in $a$. By definition of $f$, it holds that $f_a'(x^*) = 0$ for all $a \geq 0$, and $f_a''(x^*)<0$ for all $a \in [0, \overline{a})$.

Moreover, it holds that for $a = 0$, $x^*$ is the unique global maximizer of $f_0(x)$ (over the relevant domain).

Does it then follow from continuity of $f$ that it is always possible to find some small $\tilde{a} > 0$ such that $x^*$ is also a global maximizer (over the relevant domain) of $f_{\tilde{a}}(x)$, for fixed $\tilde{a}$?

Here are some thoughts: As $f_a(x)$ is continuous in $x$ and $a$, one can always find a small enough $a$ such that $|f_0(x)-f_a(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in [\underline{x}, \overline{x}]$. Hence, one can always find an $a$ that gives rises to a new global maximum (over the relevant domain) that is arbitrarily close to $f_0(x^*)$.

But given that $f_a'(x^*) = 0$ for all $a\geq 0$, and $f_a''(x^*)<0$ for all $a \in [0, \overline{a})$ by the construction of $f$, can one guarantee that $x^*$ stays a global maximizer if one chooses a sufficiently small $a$?

I'm pretty much lost here. In all numerical simulations that I did for my specific problem, this property seems to hold. But I just cannot prove it. Many thanks in advance for any helpful thoughts you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_a(x)=ax^4-x^2$ and $x^*=0$.

[EDIT] The added condition of compactness does not change the result, it just makes the counterexample less simple.

Let $g\colon\mathbb R\to [0,\infty)$ be an even smooth function such that $g(x)=0$ for $|x|\ge 1$,  $g(0)=1$, $g'(0)=0$ and $g''(0)>0$. (It is not too difficult to write down such a function explicitly).
Let $f\colon[-1,1]\to \mathbb R$ be a smooth function with $f'(0)=0$, $f''(0)<0$ and $f(x)<f(0)$ for all $x\ne 0$ (in other words, $f$ can play the role of $f_0$ with $\underline x=-1$, $x^*=0$, $\overline x=1$).
Let 
$$f_a(x) = \begin{cases}f(x)-a\cdot g\left(x/a\right)&\text{if }a\ne0,\\
f(x)&\text{if }a=0.\end{cases} $$
Then $(a,x)\mapsto f_a(x)$ is continuous and also for $a\ne 0$ we have that 
$f_a'(0)=f'(0)-g'(0)=0$ and $f_a''(0)=f''(0)-ag''(0)<0$ for $a$ sufficiently small (namely for $a<\frac{-f''(0)}{g''(0)}$).
Further we have $f_a(a)=f(0)+\frac12f''(0)a^2+o(a^3)$ and $f_a(0)=f(0)-a$.
Therefore $x^*0$ is a local maximizer but fails to be a global maximizer for all sufficiently small positive $a$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this counter-example! So it does not work in general. I'll have to think about how my problem (which the above was supposed to be a simplified version of) differs from the current formulation, as I could not find any proper counter-examples so far. This might have something to do with my range for $x$ being a compact interval, or that I deal with distribution functions. I hope that I can update the question tomorrow.

Comment: I've now edited the question to better suit my specific example. I would be extremely grateful for any insights on this. Also, if it is possible to generate a counterexample, any ideas how to do this would be highly valuable to me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Many thanks for this detailed counter-example. I think that you made a minor mistake when calculating $f_a''(0)$, which I think should rather be given by $f_a''(0) = f''(0) - g''(0)/a$, leading to the condition $a < \frac{g''(0)}{f''(0)}$. However, your proof can easily be fixed if we let $g''(0) < 0$ instead of $g''(0) > 0$. Am I correct here? If that is the case, I will happily accept your answer (which is quite surprising to me)!

Comment: Actually, the above comment is incorrect, as the condition $f_a''(0) = f''(0) - g''(0)/a < 0$ implies that $a > \frac{g''(0)}{f''(0)}$, as $f''(0) < 0$. But then, we don't have anything to say about the case where $a$ is small, so your counter-example doesn't seem to work. Maybe it can be fixed...?

Comment: OK, I think I could finally fix your counter-example. As you suggested originally, we let $g''(0) > 0$. Then $f_a''(0) < 0$ implies that $a > \frac{g''(0)}{f''(0)}$, which is always true since $a \geq 0$, but the RHS is negative. Then everything goes through. I could already construct a direct counter-example with $f(x) = -(x-1/2)(x+1/2)$, and $g(x)$ being the pdf of a 50/50 mixture-distribution of two Gaussian-random variables, one with mean $-0.2$, the other with mean $0.2$, and both with a standard deviation of 0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an image of the counter-example discussed in my comment above.

In the graph, the horizontal axis is $x$, and the vertical axis is $a$. One can see that $x=0$ is only a global optimum for $a = 0$, but remains a local maximum for all $a > 0$.

[image]